# How to move a json and separate the results received?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using this Microsoft API:

> https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

I get her json with this "code":

> https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa

However I need to separate the information and add them in the collection-item of the materialize framework, such as:

> INSERT THE BRAND NAME

MY CODE:

```
function PesquisaVisualComputacional(){

  // CHAVE DE INSCRIÇÃO DA API.
  var API_KEY = "---";

  // Deve-se utilizar a mesma região em que a chave de escrição da API está
  // NOTA: As chaves de inscrições de testes são geradas na região "Westcentralus".
  var uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?";

  // Solicitar Parâmetros de Retorno do JSON.
  var params = {
    "visualFeatures": "Categories,Tags,Description,Faces,ImageType,Color,Adult",
    "details": "Celebrities,Landmarks",
    "language": "en"
  };

  // MOSTRA A IMAGEM RECEBIDA DA URL
  var sourceImageUrl = document.getElementById("inserirURLImagem").value;
  document.querySelector("#sourceImagem").src = sourceImageUrl;

  // Executa a chamada da API RESTFULL via AJAX.
  $.ajax({

    // Utiliza a uriBase para retornar os valores dos Parâmetros
    url: uriBase + $.param(params),

    // Solicita os Headers
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
      xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
      xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", API_KEY);
    },

    // Tipo do AJAX
    type: "POST",

    // Solicita o Body
    data: '{"url": ' + '"' + sourceImageUrl + '"}',
  })

  .done(function(data) {
    // CODE JSON HERE
    //$("#responseTextArea").val(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Mostra as mensagens de Erro.
    var errorString = (errorThrown === "") ? "Error. " : errorThrown + " (" + jqXHR.status + "): ";
    errorString += (jqXHR.responseText === "") ? "" : jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message;
    alert(errorString);
  });

};
```

Comment: could you may translate your spanish to english? (or have alook at http://es.stackoverflow.com), also a sample input would be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
.done(function(data) {
// CODE JSON HERE
console.log(data)
$("#responseTextArea").append(data.name);
```

});

For a name, you can use a particular field from data.